# What does 元本払戻金 mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm curious what 元本払戻金 means (in a financial/investment context), if there is a corresponding single English word, and how it is pronounced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## **元本払戻金【がん.ぽん.はらい.もどし.きん】（特別分配金【とくべつぶんぱいきん】）**

元本払戻金 is a technical term from the field of [投資信託【とうししんたく】, investment funding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investment_fund). Formerly, it was called 特別分配金, but the name got changed to avoid confusion relating to tax exemption (see source 2 below).

In short, it refers to a special dividend that is tax free. Each investor has got a 個別元本【こべつがんぽん】 (X), initially the cost basis, the value of the shares when you bought it (or averaged if you bought more). Now suppose a divident (value Y) is paid back. If the current value of the share is greater or equal to your 個別元本, Z≧X, you need to pay taxes normally. If it smaller, the entire dividend is tax free if X-Z≧Y;  or only a part of it, ie. Y-(Z-X), otherwise. Afterwards, the 個別元本 is reduced by the tax-free amount.

For example (taken from the third source below):

- value of share when you buy it: X=10,500
- value when divident is paid: Z=10,700
- divident to be paid: Y=300

In this case, part of the divident is tax-free, ie. Y-(X-Z)=300-(10700-10500)=100. You need to pay taxes for the remaining 200. Afterwards, you 個別元本 is reduced to 10500-100=10400.

Sources, and some pages explaining it in detail.

- [Nissay Asset Management Corporation](http://www.nam.co.jp/seminar/rescue/operation/dividends/b10.html)
- [The Bank of Saga Ltd.](http://www.sagabank.co.jp/unyou/toushin/saginsensei/vol6.html)
- [Kokusai Asset Management Co., Ltd.](http://www.kokusai-am.co.jp/simulation/calculator/bunpaikin/kaisetsu.html)

---

The closest equivalent in English I found is this: [Trade King, Mutual Funds and Taxes](https://www.tradeking.com/education/mutual-funds/tax-guide).

> Nontaxable return of capital
>
> It's possible for a mutual fund to make a distribution to you without your having to pay tax on it. This generally occurs when a distribution involves recovery of all or a portion of your cost basis (i.e., the amount of your investment) in the fund. Such a distribution is not subject to taxation because it does not represent investment earnings. It still must be reported on your tax return, however.

Essentially, the 元本払戻金 is supposed to be a return of your investment (元本). So my suggestion for a close English translation of 元本払戻金(特別分配金) would be `cost basis distribution/return/dividend (special divident)`. 普通分配金 would be `normal divident`. You should consult with a professional translation service if you need this for legal purposes.

---

**Disclaimer**: This is not legal or financial advice. I know only what I read on the net.

Answer (score 0):

「元本払戻金」 is read 「がんぽんはらいもどしきん」 and it basically means the same thing as "capital dividend" in English in the investment world.

It is a tax-free dividend, I might add.